# The var keyword scope and function name used to access variables

Tags: javascript, var

How is prop1 still accessible outside function body?

```js
function myFunc() {
  var prop1 = 10;
  this.myChildFunc = function() {
    alert("value of prop1: " + prop1);
  }
}

myFunc();
myFunc.prop1 = 20; // How prop1 is still accessible using function name ? and outside function scope?
alert("prop1:" + myFunc.prop1);
```

Comment: this can help you https://dev.to/simplymichael/variable-declaration-and-scoping-rules-c0k

Comment: `myFunc.prop1` is **not** the same thing as `var prop1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects, so they can have properties, but these are just properties, nothing more than that.

So, the *variable* you've declared inside the function (`var prop1`) **has nothing to do** with the *property* on the function object (`myFunc.prop1`). They just have the same name.

To see it, let's look at this:

```js
function myFunc() {
  var prop1 = 10;
  console.log(prop1);
}

myFunc();                  //10
console.log(myFunc.prop1); //undefined - no such property
myFunc.prop1=20;           //myFunc.prop1 is now 20
myFunc();                  //variable is still 10
console.log(myFunc.prop1); //property is still 20
```

Comment: ohkk. So when I write myFunc() its a call to function and when I write myFunc. it means I am accessible the **object** _myFunc_
@FZs under which topic can I learn more about this?

Comment: @Garvit For example, this [javascript.info article](https://javascript.info/function-object) looks good to me...